# How to trigger selection of an option using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

This syntax is able to change the `Select` option but then clicking on Submit button is doing nothing:

```
 $('#nbSelect  option[value="' + user_selections.bid_details.paytm_bank_2nd + '"]')
 .prop('selected', true);
```

How to simulate this selection as real user selection when page is using AngularJS  using Javascript?

Comment: If you're using Angular, you largely **shouldn't** be using jQuery at the same time. If you're editing *someone else's* Angular page via an extension, then you'll need to access `item.selectedVariant` per the linked answer.

Comment: All answers in the linked topic seem completely irrelevant here since an extension can't just change the internal state that's not exposed via a global variable. Instead you can try to fire the change event in the hopes the page processes it: $('your selector')[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {bubbles: true}))

Comment: @ceejayoz [Change value of wrapped select, that was dynamically created by AngularJs from Chrome content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/37348526) is the proper target, apparently.